# How to detect if @Cacheable method output comes from cache?

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-annotations, spring-cache

There is a method annotated with @Cacheable that returns an object:

```java
@Service
public class UserService {

  @Cacheable("userData")
  public UserData getUserData(String userName) {
    UserData userData = new UserData();
    userData.setGotFromCache(false);
    return userData;
  }

}
```

And the UserData object:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserData {
  private boolean gotFromCache;
}
```

How to detect whether method annotated @Cacheable was called or whether its output comes from cache?

The workaround is to inject CacheManager and detect it manually:

```java
Cache cache = this.cacheManager.getCache("userData");
UserData userData = null;
String userName = "some user name";
if (cache != null) {
  Object key = SimpleKeyGenerator.generateKey(userName);
  userData = cache.get(key, UserData.class);
  if (userData != null) {
    userData.setGotFromCache(true);
  } else {
    userData = userService.getUserData(userName);
    cache.put(key, userData);
  }
} else {
  userData = userService.getUserData(userName);
}
```

However, this code doesn't utilize @Cacheable annotation for the simplicity.

Is it possible to use @Cacheable and detect whether output comes from cache?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on when you need to detect - at runtime when the application is deployed, or during development.

Either way, the basic idea is same: there must be an underlying data source such as a database (UserRepository?) or API call or something else.

At runtime, you can check if the the data source is invoked, either via logging or tracing (eg using Zipkin).

--or--

During development, you can write unit tests for `UserService` that mock the datasource, and verify that there were "zero interactions" with the mock object, indicating that the data was in fact fetched from cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the userdata and see if the value returned is the old one or the new one